# Keycloak http Claim information provider

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, claims-based-identity

We have chosen keycloak to do Authentication & Authorization for spring-boot services. We have successfully implemented `RBAC` usecase. But we want to move onto `ABAC` where it gives us lot of control. We looked at CIP (Claim Information Point) and tested it with pushing claim from app.properties and verifying it in js policy. But our requirement is to get the http method type and verify whether it is GET/POST/PUT/DELETE etc and then decide whether to allow or not by role. We achived it throw below config in application.properties

```
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].path=/*
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.paths[0].claimInformationPointConfig.claims[claim-from-method]={request.method}
```

And verifying that in js policy as below

```
var context = $evaluation.context;

var attributes = context.attributes;

if (attributes.containsValue('some-claim', 'claim-value')) {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

But i have seen there is `HttpClaimInformationPointProvider` and **so wants to find out is there any way that we can verify it directly in js-policy without pushing it from app.properties.**

Comment: is https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/authorization_services/topics/enforcer-claim-information-point.adoc#claim-information-provider-spi going to help you?